# Global variables out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

In my program I have global variables at the top that are used by various functions in the game. When they are called sometimes they come up as undefined in the console. I have been playing around for so long with it but cannot seem to find the source of the problem. Is it because they are arrays, or is there another reason?

```
var randomWord = [];
var listOfWords = [];
var gridSize = [];
var populationNumber = [];
var completionNumber = [];
var attemptNumber = [];
```

Here is a fiddle with the script in...

http://jsfiddle.net/sYDs4/1/

Comment: That jsFiddle has not been changed to use jQuery. There's also no HTML, and it seems there should be some...

Comment: Please fix the JS Fiddle

Comment: In `nextButton` and `closeButton` the `randomWord` variable is used as a number, not an array.

Comment: how can I make it so that it uses it as an array? @jaudette

Comment: in `createGrid` function, you define local variables in an if statement with the same name as the global variables `populationNumber` and `completionNumber` as numbers and not arrays.

Comment: Could you show me what you mean in an updated fiddle please? @jaudette

Comment: @Milo-J I think you should check your naming. Some variables seems to be redefined or used in multiple ways. You should rename the local variables with different names than the global ones. And never declare a var in an if statement.

Comment: Ok I see. I had everything on one big function before so it was never an issue. I have only just started separating and am very new to jquery. Could you send me an updated fiddle? @jaudette

Comment: 1, Paste code into [JSLint](http://jslint.com/). 2, Cry. You can use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) if you don't want to cry as much. These will point out the majority of problems with JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few comments that do not fit in comments...

```
   if (populationNumber >= 6) {
        var populationNumber = 6;
    }
    if (completionNumber >= 6) {
        var completionNumber = 6;
    }
```

should not be done in JS, this is dangerous as you create a local variable with the same name as the global one. Without even mentioning that you assign a number to a variable supposed to be an array (the global one).

```
function nextButton() {
    //Next question click event
    $('td').removeClass('highlight-problem');
    var r = randomWord;
    while (r == randomWord) {
        randomWord = Math.floor(Math.random() * (listOfWords.length));
    }
```

This assigns a number to `randomWord` which is used as an array in other places but as a number in this function. The same goes for the `closeButton` function too.